# Adding space after listings example

Tags: listings, showexpl

I'm using the [`showexpl`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/showexpl/) package for creating codes with the displayed result. For the example settings I used `pos=b`, placing the output *below* the code, which is what I want. The problem is that now I cannot add space below the whole example, because `belowskip` seems to always add the space below the code, so it now separates the code and the output. On the other side, `aboveskip` works fine.

This is a MWE of my setup:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrbook}
\usepackage{showexpl,xcolor,lipsum}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\lstset{
explpreset=
{vsep=6pt,pos=b},
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},
xleftmargin=0cm,
numbers=none,
breaklines=true,
breakindent=0pt,
aboveskip=\baselineskip,
%belowskip=\baselineskip,
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{LTXexample}
$e^{\pi i}-1=0  $
\end{LTXexample}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I've commented the line which produces the problem. Is there a way to add space after the example? I don't want to add space manually after every `\end{LTXexample}`.

EDIT: added `parskip=full` option, as it is being used and it affects the problem.

Comment: The problem seems to be in your use of  `vsep=6pt` inside the `\explpreset` settings. If you change this to `vsep=-9pt` then the input and output come back together. I haven't posted this as a solution as the spaces at the top an bottom of the `LTXeample` environments are not equal. Incidentally, it should be possible to use `lineskip` inside `\lstset` but thisbreaks the `backgroundcolor` setting...which looks like a bug.

Comment: Setting `vsep=-9pt` looks like a dirty trick, although it can certainly work. Something like that and `aboveskip=.5\baselineskip` gives approximately equal spaces, but I would like a cleaner solution (if possible).

Comment: Yes, I would like a cleaner solution too. That's why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: I've just skimmed through the source code, and `showexpl` doesn't seem to have an option to add, let's say, `\topsep` or `\bottomsep` lengths precisely to control the top and bottom separation of the example code from the rest of the text. I think you may request these features to the maintainer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commented `%belowskip=\baselineskip` in the MWE adds the space at the end of the listing, i.e. *before* the result, not *after* the result; the `aboveskip=\baselineskip` assignment works because there is nothing before the code listing to interfere with the space.

I would add the space at the end of the definition of the `LTXexample` environment; but instead of redefining the whole environment, I would simply add the space to the definition of the `\SX@put@code@result` macro called at the end of the environment. So, using `\g@addto@macro` from LaTeX2e kernel, I would add the following before the `\begin{document}` in your MWE.

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\SX@put@code@result}{\vskip\baselineskip}
\makeatother
```

This works on my console.

Comment: Nice use of `\addto`!  Of course, then he has to load `babel` for completely non-language-related reasons.  I thought about defining a wrapper for the `LTXexample` environment, but couldn't get it to work.  In my solution, he can tweak it however he likes; yours is shorter.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii. No: that's why I added the definition manually. Yes: with english as the main language. BTW, if you asked me, `\addto` is so handy that I would add `\addto` to the kernel of LaTeX :o)

Comment: Oh, I see; skimmed too quickly.  Yes, well played.

Comment: As @dgoodmaniii suggests, I wouldn't load the whole of `babel.sty` and `english.ldf` adding the line `\usepackage[english]{babel}` to the preamble; but nothing prevents the op to copy only this macro definition in their source code.

Comment: @Lusr56: The LaTeX kernel has `\g@addto@macro`.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii Well, there you have it!

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti there seems to be a difference, though: contrary to babel's macro, latex's macro doesn't check for the definition of the macro to add to, and doesn't define it on the fly if undefined,

Comment: Yes, indeed.  But in your case `\g@addto@macro` works fine, doesn't it?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti `\g@addto@macro` works indeed; thanks for the tip. It's only that somehow I'm addicted to Babel's `\addto`, since I need babel for my native language documents anyway :o)

Comment: I didn't thought it would be relevant, but in fact I have babel.sty with the spanish option. Maybe I should edit the question to add that.

Comment: @Majoko I don't think that's necessary; the current answer works without defining new commands or loading more packages, so it is fairly general.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm not sure what you mean by "more elegant", but have you considered simply cheating?

(I'm assuming here that the OP and commenter have exhausted the options with the package itself; the solution I'm positing here is not ideal, if there were a package option to cover the circumstance.)

That is, you're using `LTXexample`, which is defined in `showexpl` by means of a `\lstnewenvironment` command.  You want behavior different from that in the default `LTXexample` environment.  So don't use `LTXexample`; using something very similar, but which adds a bit more space at the bottom.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrbook}
\usepackage{showexpl,xcolor,lipsum,listings}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\lstset{
explpreset=
{vsep=6pt,pos=b},
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},
xleftmargin=0cm,
numbers=none,
breaklines=true,
breakindent=0pt,
aboveskip=\baselineskip,
}
\makeatletter
\let\LTXexample\undefined
\let\LTXexample@\undefined
\let\endLTXexample@\undefined
\lstnewenvironment{myLTXexample}[1][]
{%
  \@temptokena{#1}%
  \begingroup
    \advance\c@ltxexample\@ne \advance\c@lstlisting\@ne
    \expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\SX@explpreset,#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
      \def\noexpand\SX@codefile{\SX@codefile}%
      \def\noexpand\SX@graphicname{\SX@graphicname}%
      \def\noexpand\SX@graphicparam{\SX@graphicparam}}%
  \x
  \xdef\SX@@explpreset{\the\@temptokena,codefile=\SX@codefile,
    graphic={[\SX@graphicparam]{\SX@graphicname}}}%
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox\bgroup% Warum noetig?
  \lst@BeginWriteFile{\SX@codefile}%
}
{%
  \lst@EndWriteFile\egroup
  \SX@put@code@result
  \vskip\baselineskip%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{myLTXexample}
$e^{\pi i}-1=0  $
\end{myLTXexample}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The only new line here is `\vskip\baselineskip%`; the remainder is verbatim the definition of `LTXexample`.  But it seems to produce your desired result, if I understand it correctly:

[image: myLTXexample]

Of course, you can increase or decrease the space as desired to match `aboveskip`.

This solution bulks up your preamble, but it does solve your problem without the need for manually inserting `\vskip`s after each `LTXexample`.  I've defined a new environment, but you could just override `LTXexample` yourself if you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

Yet, another approach would be to add the space after the environment with the `etoolbox` package saying

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{LTXexample}{\vskip\baselineskip}
```

Throws a warning (apparently a hook from `scrbook` used by `etoolbox` is deprecated), but still works on my console.

Comment: As this approach follows basically the same idea from your other answer, would'nt it be better if to edit this one into your original one?

Comment: @Ruben I thought about the same thing; and in fact the first version was an addition to the first answer; but then I realized that pretty much any answer would go along the same lines (how to append \vspace to the list), the two answers are fairly different: one uses a built-in feature of LaTeX, and the other requires loading yet another package. I asked at Meta and the answer was that including different answers in the same post or in different ones may vary from case to case.

Comment: I agree with Ruben: this would be better included as an edit to your first answer because it is basically the same solution but with a different (essentially) equivalent mechanism.